# Analyse reasons for Sudden Drop in Traffic

Tags: seo, ranking, web-traffic

My site www canada updates dot com (remove spaces) had decent traffic till a month ago and now it has dropped to about 1/3rd. I would be thankful if any one could help and analyse giving exact reasons for the drop in traffic

Comment: Maybe my answer [*here*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31893/13618) is relevant to your case as well. Second, using [*Google analytics*](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to monitor traffic could help.

Comment: This is really not helpful. Can you be more specific please? Do you have analytics software running? Hard facts? Do you know of any changes onpage that could lead to the drop? Is there a drop at all? How did you measure? What kind of traffic dropped (direct, organic, social...)? How should anyone be able to give "exact reasons"???

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to Google Webmaster Tools. It can [track sudden spikes or drops occur & send email alerts](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/search-queries-alerts-in-webmaster-tools.html). You can enable email notifications from the [Webmaster Tools Preferences page](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/preferences).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the traffic you were getting before was not relevant to your content, such as an aggressive crawler, or a secret porn stash, and it went away for reasons of its own.

Comparing webalyzer data for old and new situations might provide some clues - maybe a major incoming link dropped you.

Answer (score -2):

Google is not the answer here.  Look over your web server log files as they will tell you trends and habits of all your traffic.  Google is VERY selective with their webmaster tools and analytics and should NEVER be used as THE go to source of your web traffic.  Learn how to read and analyze your log files as they can tell you everything you need to know about your traffic.

Comment: I think you got downvoted because that sounds like a bit on an anti-Google rant which is a pity since the other advice you gave might have been considered sound. Consider rewriting your answer while just focusing on facts and evidence.